# Using Stanford CoreNLP for CorefResolution

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford CoreNLP to perform Coref resolution. The version I use is stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09. Basically, I have wrote some classes:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;


public class CorefResolution {
    public static String corefResolute(String text, List<String> tokenToReplace) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(doc);

        Map<Integer, CorefChain> corefs = doc.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(corefs);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        List<String> resolved = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            List<CoreLabel> tokens = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);

            for (CoreLabel token : tokens) {

                Integer corefClustId = token.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefClusterIdAnnotation.class);
                token.get(Coref)

                if (corefClustId == null) {
                    System.out.println("NULL NULL NULL\n");
                    resolved.add(token.word());
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Exist Exist Exist\n");
                }

                System.out.println("coreClustId is "+corefClustId.toString()+"\n");
                CorefChain chain = corefs.get(corefClustId);

                if (chain == null || chain.getMentionsInTextualOrder().size() == 1) {
                    resolved.add(token.word());
                } else {
                    int sentINdx = chain.getRepresentativeMention().sentNum - 1;
                    CoreMap corefSentence = sentences.get(sentINdx);
                    List<CoreLabel> corefSentenceTokens = corefSentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);

                    CorefChain.CorefMention reprMent = chain.getRepresentativeMention();

                    if (tokenToReplace.contains(token.word())) {
                        for (int i = reprMent.startIndex; i < reprMent.endIndex; i++) {
                            CoreLabel matchedLabel = corefSentenceTokens.get(i - 1);
                            resolved.add(matchedLabel.word());
                        }
                    } else {
                        resolved.add(token.word());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Detokenizer detokenizer = new Detokenizer();
        String resolvedStr = detokenizer.detokenize(resolved);

        return resolvedStr;
    }
}
```

Another class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Detokenizer {

    public String detokenize(List<String> tokens) {
        //Define list of punctuation characters that should NOT have spaces before or after
        List<String> noSpaceBefore = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(",", ".",";", ":", ")", "}", "]", "'", "'s", "n't"));
        List<String> noSpaceAfter = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("(", "[","{", "\"",""));

        StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder();

        tokens.add(0, "");  //Add an empty token at the beginning because loop checks as position-1 and "" is in noSpaceAfter
        for (int i = 1; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            if (noSpaceBefore.contains(tokens.get(i))
                    || noSpaceAfter.contains(tokens.get(i - 1))) {
                sentence.append(tokens.get(i));
            } else {
                sentence.append(" " + tokens.get(i));
            }

            // Assumption that opening double quotes are always followed by matching closing double quotes
            // This block switches the " to the other set after each occurrence
            // ie The first double quotes should have no space after, then the 2nd double quotes should have no space before
            if ("\"".equals(tokens.get(i - 1))) {
                if (noSpaceAfter.contains("\"")) {
                    noSpaceAfter.remove("\"");
                    noSpaceBefore.add("\"");
                } else {
                    noSpaceAfter.add("\"");
                    noSpaceBefore.remove("\"");
                }
            }
        }
        return sentence.toString();
    }
}
```

Another class file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class PlainTextCorefResolver {

    public static void resolveFile(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputFile, "UTF-8");


            if (inputFile.exists()) System.out.println("input exist\n");
            else System.out.println("input not exist\n");

            if (outputFile.exists()) System.out.println("output exist\n");
            else System.out.println("output not exist\n");

            while(true){
                String line = reader.readLine();
                //EOF
                if(line == null)
                    break;
                //Resolve line
                List<String> tokenToReplace = Arrays.asList("He", "he", "She", "she", "It", "it", "They", "they"); //!!!
                String resolvedLine = CorefResolution.corefResolute(line, tokenToReplace);
                writer.println(resolvedLine);
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Failed to open/resolve input file [" +inputFile.getAbsoluteFile()+ "] in loader");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputFileName = "path/file.txt";
        String outputFileName =  "path/file.resolved.txt";
        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
        resolveFile(inputFile, outputFile);
    }

}
```

However, it doesn't give any useful result. The corefClusterId is always null, thus I always get a bunch of "NULL NULL NULL" outputs.

How can I correctly perform coreference resolution to replace such as "He/he/She/she/It/it/The stadium/..." with its most typical mention (person or organization's name)?

For example, given:
"Estadio El Madrigal is a stadium in Spain, used since 1923. It is currently mostly used for football matches."
I want to get
"Estadio El Madrigal is a stadium in Spain, used since 1923. Estadio El Madrigal is currently mostly used for football matches."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think our coref system is attaching "Estadio El Madrigal" to "It" in your example.

Here is some example code for accessing the CorefChains and mentions in general.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.Mention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.*;

public class CorefExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Annotation document = new Annotation("John Kerry is the secretary of state.  He ran for president in 2004.");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("coref chains");
        for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
            System.out.println("\t"+cc);
            System.out.println(cc.getMentionMap());
            List<CorefChain.CorefMention> corefMentions = cc.getMentionsInTextualOrder();
            for (CorefChain.CorefMention cm : corefMentions) {
                System.out.println("---");
                System.out.println("full text: "+cm.mentionSpan);
                System.out.println("position: "+cm.position);
                System.out.println("start index of first word: "+cm.startIndex);
            }
        }
        for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            System.out.println("---");
            System.out.println("mentions");
            for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.println("\t"+m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

======================
**Update**
@StanfordNLPHelper, there is the error I get when using "coref" rather than "dcoref":

```
INFO: Read 25 rules
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... 
done [0.3 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator mention
Using mention detector type: rule
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3079)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2874)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1639)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1394)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:324)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.SimpleLinearClassifier.<init>(SimpleLinearClassifier.java:30)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.PairwiseModel.<init>(PairwiseModel.java:75)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.PairwiseModel$Builder.build(PairwiseModel.java:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.ClusteringCorefSystem.<init>(ClusteringCorefSystem.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.StatisticalCorefSystem.fromProps(StatisticalCorefSystem.java:48)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefAnnotator.<init>(CorefAnnotator.java:66)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.coref(AnnotatorImplementations.java:220)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$13.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:515)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! One small problem is it seems should be  props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,dcoref"); rather than ``coref". (As it has bug when testing on my laptop... I am not quite clear about the difference between coref and decoref)

Comment: What bug are you seeing?  It should definitely be "coref" since version 3.6.0.  Do you have the latest jars in your classpath?

Comment: Hi, I tested again using the latest Stanford CoreNLP. If I use "coref",the output is put on above. "decoref" doesn't have problem.

Comment: I don't think the new coref is assigning corefID's which is an issue we need to address.  But in my sample code you can see how to find the text positions of the various mentions in the coref cluster.

Comment: I just saw your bug posting, you are getting an out of memory issue.  You need to run your JVM with more RAM.  The latest coref requires "6GB".  You should use the older dcoref if you need to use less RAM.  More details here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html